# Automatic translation of hotkeys in Qt linguist

Tags: qt, internationalization, qt4

Example: The translation files of the [qet](http://qelectrotech.org/)-project provide several strings like
`"Ctrl + Alt + C"`. All these strings could be translated to different languages by a computer with simple substitution rules like `"Ctrl" -> "Strg"` for german language.

How can I translate it automatic?

Comment: How do you show the original `Ctrl + Alt + C` string in your application? Is it displayed in main menu automatically or do you use some code?

Comment: It is not an answer to my question.

Comment: `setShortcut(QKeySequence(tr("Ctrl+Shift+X")));`

Comment: It is how you set the shortcut. How do you **display** it? Where must the translation take effect?

Comment: it is displayed next to the menu items

Comment: As far as I know, several shortcuts are already translated in the Qt qm files. Did you try those?

Comment: @Martin sounds interesting. Do you have a link about this?

Comment: @JonasStein I have no link, but in subfolder `translations` in the Qt installation folder you can find e.g. `qt_de.ts` which translates `Ctrl+F10` as `Ctrl+F10`, but `Ctrl` as `Strg`. Search for `QShortcut` in the ts file.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the solution is to use predefined Qt constants instead of strings. These may be translated by Qt if I understand it correctly.

https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qkeysequence.html#StandardKey-enum

I will need a solution for missing hotkeys then. 
If it would be a simple text file I could run search and replace over it.